# Getting device token when user clicks "Don't Allow" and then later turns notification switch on in Apple Settings

Tags: ios, push-notification

If a user taps "Don't allow" when I prompt them to allow push notifications and then later goes into apple settings and switches the "allow notifications" Boolean from off to on, how can I now get the device token to send them push notifications?

Comment: The next time your app is launched you will get a call to the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` app delegate method

Comment: You need to register for notifications when your `applicationDidFinishLaunching`. You can't get the device token if your app isn't even running and the user disallowed it. You can only do it when ApplicationDidEnterForeground or ApplicationDidFinishLaunching or similar.